# Cauchy problem $y' = y + 10\sin y, y(0) = a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a Cauchy problem:
 $y' = y + 10\sin y, y(0) = a$

It is need to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial a} \Big|_a$ where $a = 0$.

I don't know what to do here. Could you help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Are you trying to find the derivative at $0$?

Comment: Since $y(0)=a$, the derivative of $y$ at $0$ is simply $y'(0)=y(0)+10\sin y(0)=a+10\sin a$. (you should not use the same name $a$ below in the derivative, it makes things less clear, and it's not a partial derivative since $y$ is a function of one variable)

Comment: If the question is as stated, it seems to me that you need to solve the equation for $y$ and then differentiate with respect to $a$. Note the equation is separable.

Comment: The way I read this, $a$ is a *parameter* but not the independent variable.  $y'(x) = y(x) + 10\sin y(x)$, correct?

Comment: So you want to find $\partial y/\partial a$ as a function of $x$ when $a = 0$, right?

Comment: More generally, let $y(a,\ )$ denote the solution of $y'=g(y)$ such that $y(0)=a$, for some differentiable function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$, then $$\left.\frac{\partial y(a,x)}{\partial a}\right|_{a=0}=e^{g'(0)x}.$$

Comment: @Did:  very nice observation; thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret this question as follows, as indicated in my comments:  given the ordinary differential equation

$\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx} = y'(x) = y(x) + 10 \sin y(x) \tag{1}$

with

$y(0) = a, \tag{2}$

we can actually think of $y$ as a function $y(x, a)$ of the *two* variables $x$ and $a$; for each value of $a$, we obtain a unique trajectory $y(x, a)$ satisfying $y(0, a) = a$.  Bearing this in mind, and *assuming* for the moment that $y(x, a)$ is sufficiently differentiable as a function of *both* $x$ and $a$, it follows that the derivative $\partial y(x, a) / \partial a$ is a meaningful quantity; indeed, for fixed $a$ it metrics the varying rate of change of the trajectory $y(x, a)$ with respect to the initial point as we travel along an integral curve of (1).  For this reason, as well as a certain amount of experience I have had with similar problems, I assume the OP is asking for $(\partial y(x, a) \partial a)_{a = 0}$ as a *function* of $x$; indeed, if all that is wanted is

$(\dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{\partial a})_{x = 0, a = 0} = (\dfrac{\partial y(0, a)}{\partial a})_{a = 0} = \dfrac{\partial a}{\partial a} = 1, \tag{3}$

there is not much question here.

To find $(\partial y(x, a) / \partial a)$ as a function of $x$ we may proceed as follows:

Since the function $y + 10 \sin y$ is analytic in $y$, the solution $y(x, a)$, is an analytic function of the two variables $x$ and $a$.  Therefore all partial derivatives of $y(x, a)$ in $x$ and $a$ exist and may be taken in any order; in particular

$\dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{ \partial x \partial a} = \dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{ \partial a \partial x}; \tag{4}$

for notational convenience, I introduce the convention

$y_a(x, a) = \dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{\partial a}; \tag{5}$

then (4) reads

$\dfrac{\partial y_a(x, a)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a} (\dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{\partial x}); \tag{6}$

using (1), (6) may be written

$\dfrac{\partial y_a(x, a)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}(y(x, a) + 10 \sin y(x, a)); \tag{7}$

using the chain rule *et al*:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}(y(x, a) + 10 \sin y(x, a)) = y_a(x, a) + 10 y_a(x, a) \cos y(x, a)$
$= (1 + 10 \cos y(x, a))y_a(x, a); \tag{8}$

whence (7) becomes

$\dfrac{\partial y_a(x, a)}{\partial x} = (1 + 10 \cos y(x, a))y_a(x, a); \tag{9}$

of course since $y(0, a) = a$, we take the initial condition associated with this equation to be

$\dfrac{\partial y(0, a)}{ \partial a} = 1; \tag{10}$

(9) is a first order, one- dimensional, ordinary, linear, homogeneous equation for $y_a(x, a)$ with non-constant coefficient $1 + \cos y(x, a)$; it is common knowledge that the solution to (9) with any given $(\partial y(0, a) / \partial y)$ is

$\dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{\partial a} = \dfrac{\partial y(0, a)}{\partial a} e^{\int_0^x(1 + 10 \cos y(s,a)) ds}; \tag{11}$

(11) is easily verified by direct differentiation; that it satisfies the requisite initial condition is also easily seen by simply setting $x = 0$.  I leave these (essentially) no-work details to be filled in by my readers.  Inspecting (11), we see that the integral occurring in the exponential in fact depends on the solution $y(x, a)$ to (1) starting at $y = a$: we need to know this solution to evaluate (11).  This piece of the puzzle is provided by the observation that the solution to (1) with $a = 0$, is in fact the constant solution $0$:

$y(x, 0) = 0; \tag{12}$

(12) also readily checked by direct substitution into (1), (2). Since

$\cos y(x, 0) = \cos 0 = 1 \tag{13}$

for all $x$, we see that

$\dfrac{\partial y(x, 0)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial y(0, 0)}{\partial a} e^{\int_0^x (1 + 10 \cos y(s, 0)) ds} = \dfrac{\partial y(0, 0)}{\partial a} e^{\int_0^x (1 + 10 \cos 0)ds}$
$= 1 e^{\int_0^x 11ds} = e^{11x}.  \tag{14}$

To summarize,

$(\dfrac{\partial y(x, a)}{\partial a})_{a= 0} = e^{11x}. \tag{15}$

***Appendix:  Some Theoretical Considerations; References:***

That unique trajectories of (1) do indeed exist follows from the *Lipschitz continuity* of the function $f(y)  = y + 10 \sin y$, which in turn may be seen to be a consequence of its differentiability; indeed

$\dfrac{df}{dy} = 1 + 10 \cos y, \tag{16}$

from which

$\vert \dfrac{df}{dy} \vert = \vert 1 + 10 \cos y \vert \le 1 + 10 \vert \cos y \vert \le 11 \tag{17}$

for all $y$; thus, for $y_2 \ge y_1$,

$\vert f(y_2) - f(y_1) \vert = \vert \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \dfrac{df}{dy} dy \vert \le \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \vert \dfrac{df}{dy} \vert dy \le \int_{y_1}^{y_2} 11 dy \le 11 \vert y_2 - y_1 \vert, \tag{18}$

while if $y_1 \ge y_2$ essentially the same calculation shows that

$\vert f(y_1) - f(y_2) \vert = \vert \int_{y_2}^{y_1} \dfrac{df}{dy} dy \vert \le \int_{y_2}^{y_1} \vert \dfrac{df}{dy} \vert dy \le \int_{y_2}^{y_1} 11 dy \le 11 \vert y_1 - y_2 \vert;\tag{19}$

from (19) and (20) we conclude that we always have

$\vert f(y_2) - f(y_1) \vert \le 11 \vert y_2 - y_1 \vert; \tag{20}$

which shows that $f(y)$ is possessed of a *global* Lipschitz constant $K = 11$.  From here the standard theory of existence and uniqueness takes over and we conclude that there is in fact a precisely *one* solution to (1) through any initial point $(x_0, y_0)$.  These essential facts are common knowledge; a detailed exposition, including proofs of all the relevant details, may be found in J. K. Hale's most excellent treatment, *Ordinary Differential Equations* (ISBN-13:  978-0-486-47212-9), Chapter I; see also the text of Hirsch, Smale and Devaney, *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* (ISBN O-12-349703-5), Chapter 17.  And again, the fact that the trajectory $y(x, a)$ is unique allows $y$ to be unabiguously *defined* as a function of $x$ and $a$.

But there's more.  $y + 10 \sin y$ is not merely Lipschitz continuous; it infinitely differentiable for all $y$, indeed (real) analytic.  From this it follows, by an extension of the theory of existence and uniqueness, that the solution $y(x, a)$ of (1) with $y(0, a) = a$ is itself infinitely differentiable in $x$ and $a$.  (Indeed, the solutions to $y'(x, a) = f(y, a)$ are $C^k$ whenever $f(y, a)$ is.)  In particular, $y(x, a)$ is a $C^2$ function of $x$ and $a$.  This fact underlies the method presented above to find that $(\partial y(x, a) / \partial a)_{a = 0} = e^{11x}$, since the differential equation for $(\partial y(x, a) / \partial a)$, i.e. (4), (7), (10), hinges on the validity of interchanging the order of the derivatives $\partial / \partial x$ and $\partial / \partial a$.  In addition to the above references, material on the differentiability of solutions, including all the relevant proofs, may be found in [these notes](http://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/555/555_notes/continuity.pdf).  ***End of Appendix.***

Answer (score 1):

let $y(t;a)$ be the unique solution of $$y' = y + 10 \sin y,\, y(0) = a. \tag 1 $$ now, differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $a$ gives $$y_a' = y_a+10\cos y \,y_a=(1+10\cos y)\,  y_a,y_a(0)= 1.$$

you can get the initial condition by looking at the integral representation of the solution $$y = a+ \int_0^x (y + 10\sin y)\,dx  \tag 2$$

differentiate $(2)$ wrt $a$ we have  $$y_a = 1 +  \int_0^x \left(y_a + 10\cos y \right)\, y_a\,dx.$$   now set $x = 0$ gives $$y_a(0) = 1$$ as before.